# I need a non-corrupted Windows 8 directory structure

Tags: windows-8

I accidentally dragged and dropped a folder up into another folder, and I can't determine which one it was.  Two minutes later my desktop background image went black, but everything else still works.  Definitely not a coincidence.  I definitely don't want to turn the computer off like this.  (I HATE tapping, rather than having to click a mouse button.  That's what happened.) I was in a file explorer window, on the left side, where the directory structure proceeds:

```
OS (C:)  
Apps  
dell  
Drivers 

...

VTRoot  
Windows
```

The `ProgramData` and `Windows` folders were expanded.

I need a complete default directory structure so I can find out what moved.  I expect it will be a tedious task.  Dell Inspiron 1521, Windows 8.0.

The background image is right where it should be, in the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Device Stage`.

I know about system restore. That's an absolute last resort as I've done a lot today.

A good solution would be if someone with Windows 8 could open a command prompt, set the directory to `c:/`, type the command `tree | clip`, and supply that here.

Comment: If you can't tell us what folder we can't help just set the background image again

Comment: There's got to be additional things besides the background image dying.  I'm not turning this thing off like this.  The directory structure should be pretty standard.  I realize a non-Dell will not have a Dell folder...

Comment: We don't email answers here at Superuser so asking isn't really acceptable behavior

Comment: Then please post the file here.  It will be VERY long.

Comment: The whole directory tree is way too long for an answer, which is limited to 30000 characters. If you start `regedit`, and navigate to `HKEY_USERS\USER\Control Panel\Desktop` The `Wallpaper` registry values contains the path to the background picture. Since the picture is gone, I guess the folder you moved was closely related.

Comment: System restore doesn't affect user files, only installed software etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell, something like this might give you an idea of where the folder was written.

The idea is the list will contain folders which had something happen in them, such as a receiving a folder.

```
$folders = get-childitem -path c:\ –recurse

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    if ($folder.Attributes -eq "Directory" -And $folder.LastWriteTime -gt "8/23/2014")
    {
        Write-Host $folder.FullName
    }
}
```

Here it is on one line:

```
$folders = get-childitem -path c:\ –recurse; foreach ($folder in $folders) { if ($folder.Attributes -eq "Directory" -And $folder.LastWriteTime -gt "8/23/2014") { Write-Host $folder.FullName }}
```

Note: `-eq` = equals; `-gt` = greater than; `"8/23/2014"` is today, but the first second of it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately it listed about 300 directories - apparently any one that had anything written to it.

Comment: @JohnW. Hmm, if you remember the hour it happened during, adding another `-And` could limit it to that period. Ex: `-And $folder.LastWriteTime -gt "8/23/2014 7:00:00 PM" -And $folder.LastWriteTime -lt "8/23/2014 8:00:00 PM"`

Comment: Your script is not accessing the c:/programdata directory. That's one of two subfolders I had opened in the tree. I intentionally made a change in there as a test. There is no error message at the beginning of the script that it can't access that directory. There are some other access errors, such as "get-childitem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\AppCompat\Programs' is denied."

Comment: @JohnW. It probably wants you to run PowerShell as admin. You can right click on it in the taskbar to see that option.

Comment: I ran it as admin this time. Less errors at the start, but it still won't access that directory.  If I set the script to just run at c:/programdata I get the following errors:

get-childitem : Access to the path 'C:\programdata\Microsoft\Windows\LocationProvider' is denied.
At line:1 char:12
+ $folders = get-childitem -path c:\programdata –recurse; foreach ($folder in $fol ...
+            ~~~
---[SNIP - too long]
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

and a couple more of the same errors regarding that directory.

Comment: @JohnW. Ahh, too bad!

Comment: Louis, How do I modify your script to output to a file.  Adding > filename.txt to the end gives an error.  I found a way to run a powershell script with system privileges by scheduling a task, but I need to catch the output in a file.

Comment: I think replacing `$Write-Host $folder.FullName` with `$folder.FullName >> C:\Users\John\Desktop\Output.txt` would work.

Comment: I'm aborting this solution.  I can't get enough info to schedule a task with system permissions.  I don't understand why the programdata directory is a problem, as I can browse it and make folders and such with no problems.  ----  I just need someone to send me the very easy to make directory tree from any Windows 8 system (instructions at the end of my posted question), and I'll find the problem from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name(s) of the folder/files you're looking for, use "Search" to look for them.  The results will show the Path to their new location.  I've used this method often on XP.  I know it sounds simplistic, but that sounds like what you want to do, unless Windows 8 dropped that feature.

You may wish to be less concerned about the Black Background until you've found the new location of the file(s).  It might just go away once you've recovered the lost folder/file(s).

Comment: I have no idea what the name of the folder was.  If I did it would be simple to use the search function to find it, and a Google search to see where it is supposed to be.